# flask - how to get parameters from a JSON GET request

Tags: python, json, flask

I have a client side api that issues the following GET request:

`"GET /tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d?{%22task%22:%22hello%22,%22url%22:%22/tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d%22}&_=1411772296171 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Doing

```
task = request.args
print task
```

shows it to be

`ImmutableMultiDict([('{"task":"hello","url":"/tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d"}', u''), ('_', u'1411772296171')])`

To get the "task" value, if I do:

```
  request.args.getlist('task')
```

I get `[]` instead of `hello`. Any ideas on how to dig out hello from this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignore `request.args` here; you don't have a form-encoded query parameter here.

Use [`request.query_string`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.query_string) instead, splitting of the cache breaker (`&_=<random number>`), decoding the URL quoting and feeding the result to `json.loads()`:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
from flask import json

data = json.loads(unquote(request.query_string.partition('&')[0]))
task = data.get('task')
```

Demo:

```
>>> request.query_string
'{%22task%22:%22hello%22,%22url%22:%22/tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d%22}&_=1411772296171'
>>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> from flask import json
>>> unquote(request.query_string.partition('&')[0])
'{"task":"hello","url":"/tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d"}'
>>> json.loads(unquote(request.query_string.partition('&')[0]))
{u'url': u'/tasks/5fe7eabd-842e-40d2-849e-409655e0891d', u'task': u'hello'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the [request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object), you should be able to use `request.args.get('key', 'default')` to get the parameter you want.

```
request.args.get('task', None)
```

Comment: Both `request.args.get('task', None)` and `request.args.get('task')` return the value `None` not `hello`.