# Decode nested objects serialized with jquery's $.param() in python/flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask

Jquery's param allows you to encode nested objects to transfer through get parameters:

```
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a=2&a=3&a=4"
// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4"

// <=1.3.2:
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 } ] });
// "a=[object+Object]&d=3&d=4&d=[object+Object]"

// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 }, d: [ 3, 4, { e: 5 } ] });
// "a[b]=1&a[c]=2&d[]=3&d[]=4&d[2][e]=5"
```

How do I decode this a list/dict in Python? As an alternative, is there any other serialization that works on nested objects that's implemented in Javascript and Python?

Comment: JSON is a protocol both Python and JavaScript (and a lot of other languages) support.

Comment: 1. Do you need to use GET? for POST, better use JSON.  2. Are you using django? flask? bottle? not sure yet?

Comment: @Udi GET of course. And Flask.

Answer (score 2):

For simple values in lists, as in `$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] })`, use `request.args.getlist("a[]")`.

For `$.param({d:{foo:123, bar:456}})`, use:

```
def get_jquery_dict(args, key):
    needle = re.compile(r"^{}\[(\w+)\](.*)$".format(key))
    d = MultiDict()
    for k, v in args.items(multi=True):
        m = needle.match(k)
        if not m:
            continue
        key = m.group(1) + m.group(2)
        d.add(key, v)
    return d

get_jquery_dict(request.args, 'd')
```

Which works for dict in dicts (`$.param({outer:{inner:{foo: 123, bar:456}}})`):

```
# ?outer[inner][foo]=123&outer[inner][bar]=456
outer = get_jquery_dict(request.args, 'outer')
inner = get_jquery_dict(outer, 'inner')
```

And lists in dicts (`$.param({foo: {bar: [10,20,30]}})`):

```
# ?foo[bar][]=10&foo[bar][]=20&foo[bar][]=30
foo = get_jquery_dict(request.args, 'foo')
bar = foo.getlist('bar[]')
```

For dictionaries in lists (`[3, 4, { e: 5 }]`), you are welcome to adapt the code above and create a `get_jquery_list()` function, or modify your data structure a bit to avoid them :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it to JSON and then use the `json` python module to read the data. This will place it in a dictionary.

You can [serialize to JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

in Javascript:

```
var JSON.stringify(your_data);
```

reading JSON in Python:

```
import json    

s = json.loads('{ "a": { "b": 1, "c": 2 }, "d": [ 3, 4, { "e": 5 } ] }')
s['a']
>>>> {'b': 1, 'c': 2}

s['a']['b']
>>>> 1
```

Flask Example using answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069714/flask-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-json-get-request), you might need to change the `query_string` argument, but it gives an idea of how it would work:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from urllib import unquote
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def process_data():
    data = json.loads(unquote(request.query_string.partition('&')[0]))
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If you can send a POST instead of GET, you can specify the data as JSON and read it straight from `request.json` in Python/Flask.

Comment: Interesting idea, transferring json via GET parameters. But it would be unreadable in an URL and the escaping will make it too large.

Comment: You could take a look at Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) to set up a rest based API  to recieve the GET request and process the data.

Comment: @aitchnyu I've added an outline of a Flask example to show how you might receive the data over http.